Getting "coverage set class table not yet supported" message with FOP 2.9 and DITA OT 4.2.3
We use Google NotoSans fonts in our PDFs. When we generated them with DITA OT 3.7.1 with FOP 2.6, we got the "coverage set class table not yet supported" warning. There were workarounds, such as setting . This wouldn't work for our Arabic PDFs. After looking at GitHub and researching Apache FOP, I noticed that there were fixes in the works. So, we ignored the message and waited until we could update to the latest DITA OT.
Now, we're migrating to DITA OT 4.2.3 with FOP 2.9. We're still getting the warning. Is there a way to fix this message or change it from WARN to INFO?
